# How to combine FancyBox with an existing div?

Tags: popup, fancybox

I'm trying to combine FancyBox with an existing div. This div includes caption hover effects. I have no idea on how to combine it though, as I don't know that much about JS yet. My HTML contains multiple pictures, this is one of them:

```
<!-- Image Caption 1 -->
  <div id="box-6" class="box">
    <img id="image-6" src="beeld/images/grafisch/image09.png"/>
    <span class="caption scale-caption">
        <h3>Scale Caption</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </span>
```

All I want is for `file:///Data$/marketing/2013/Sophia/Website/HTML/Beeld/images/bgimg.jpg` (test image) to pop-up. Right now all it does is reopen the window to show the picture.

So basically I'm trying to merge that HTML with the FancyBox HTML:

```
<a id="single_3" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_b.jpg" title="Ayvalık, Turkey (Nejdet Düzen)">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_m.jpg" alt="" />
```

Would there be any way to accomplish that?

The JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
$("#single_1").fancybox({
      helpers: {
          title : {
              type : 'float'
          }
      }
  });

$("#single_2").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'elastic',

    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'inside'
        }
    }
});

$("#single_3").fancybox({
    openEffect : 'elastic',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'outside'
        }
    }
});

$("#single_4").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type : 'over'
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I tried to merge it myself, like this:

```
<!-- Image Caption 1 -->
    <a id="single_3" href="file:///Data$/marketing/2013/Sophia/Website/HTML/Beeld/images/bgimg.jpg" title="Ayvalık, Turkey (Nejdet Düzen)">
    <div id="box-6" class="box">
    <img id="image-6" src="beeld/images/grafisch/image_09.png"/></a>
    <span class="caption scale-caption">
        <h3>Scale Caption</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
        sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </span>
```

but FancyBox simply won't popup.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does fancybox works at all? I mean are you sure it is properly loaded? Does it work in another item?

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't work on an separate image either.. could it have something to do with the JS I've posted? since I added all of the JS and CSS files to my file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) Make sure you **first** load the jquery library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2) **Then** you must load the fancybox code

```
<script src="http://yourdomain.com/your_path_to_js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

3) Then write this code in head section

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#single_3').fancybox({
        openEffect : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'outside'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

4) And this in body section

```
<a id="single_3" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_b.jpg" title="Ayvalık, Turkey (Nejdet Düzen)">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8507/8454547519_f8116520e1_m.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Here is a working demo http://jsfiddle.net/fkeVR/5/

5) make sure the file you are reffering to file:///Data$/marketing/2013/Sophia/Website/HTML/Beeld/images/bgimg.jpg **is accessible from your script**

6) make sure your javascript has no errors. If you use firefox, the console of [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) is a great help for debugging

Comment: Thanks so much! I used <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script> instead of the one you told me to use, which is why it didn't work

Comment: update your question details with the error you are getting. :)

Comment: Except.. when I click on the image in Safari it gives me an error, while Firefox doesn't. It says no file can be found on ''path''

Comment: what file? the image? fancybox loads? whats the path of the image?

Comment: This:

<a id="single_3" href="Beeld/images/bgimg.jpg" title="Ayvalık, Turkey (Nejdet Düzen)">

I changed the path to that, and right now it reopens the window and shows the image, instead of popping up

Comment: please post all the code between <a and /a> and tell me what is the result of that code

Comment: <a id="single_3" href="Beeld/images/bgimg.jpg" title="Ayvalık, Turkey (Nejdet Düzen)">
        <div id="box-6" class="box">
  <img id="image-6" src="beeld/images/grafisch/image_09.png"/>
  <span class="caption scale-caption">
  <h3>Scale Caption</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
   sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
   </span></a>
  </div>



What do you mean by the result?

Comment: please follow the steps as described in my answer.

Comment: Everything works fine now :) some of the javascript files weren't linked properly, found out about this through debugging. Thanks a lot Sharky

Comment: @Sophiaa post it as a new question :D you can mark this as accepted if it solved your problem